# Functions returns Command Completion Output

Tags: boxes, autocomplete, cells

Is there a function that returns the output as if you invoked Command Completion.

To help clarify I am looking for a function that returns the Cell Data as if you invoked `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This took some digging but at least in Version 7 the FrontEnd command is `FT`, e.g.:

```
FE`FT["Plot"]
```

[image]

You can read the definition with `` Definition[FE`FT] ``.
If you want only the Box form itself we can modify it accordingly (here for version 7):

```
templateCell[name_String] :=
 Module[{template},
  If[! StringQ@ToExpression[name <> "::usage"], $NewMessage[ToExpression@name, "usage"]];
  template = FE`getTemplateFromUsage[ToExpression[name <> "::usage"], name];
  template = FE`reparseBoxStructure[FE`makePlainText@template, name];
  Cell[BoxData[First @ FE`insertTagBox[template, name]], "Input"]
 ]
```

Now:

```
templateCell["Plot"] // CellPrint
```

[image]

```
templateCell["Plot"]
```

> ```
> Cell[BoxData[
>   RowBox[{"Plot", "[", 
>     RowBox[{TagBox[FrameBox["f"], "Placeholder"], ",", 
>       RowBox[{"{", 
>         RowBox[{TagBox[FrameBox["x"], "Placeholder"], ",", 
>           TagBox[FrameBox[SubscriptBox["x", "min"]], "Placeholder"], ",", 
>           TagBox[FrameBox[SubscriptBox["x", "max"]], "Placeholder"]}], "}"}]}], 
>     "]"}]], "Input"]
> ```

Comment: Also in 9. It also takes a second argument (integer) to get the nth template

Comment: @rm-rf The second argument was apparently added after v7.

Comment: Quite likely, since that's when support for multiple templates was added. FWIW, it simply calls `Part` on the list. So there's `{template1, template2}` inside and you can use all integers that are valid part specifications to index this list. So `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2` all work and give what's expected.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Is there a function that returns the `CellData` instead of adding a new cell to the current Notebook?  I plan to likely use this in a Package `.m` if context helps.