# What is the real default CellEvaluationFunction?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, implementation-details, cells

The default [`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEvaluationFunction.html) is `Identity` but one can quickly see that this is handled specially as an equivalent function, `(# &)`, does not work at all the same.  The sole example in the documentation uses [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html) but this also does not work the same, returning only the output of the last line in the Input Cell:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction -> ToExpression]
```

Now in one cell:

```
2 + 2
5 + 7
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

My question is then:  What is the *real* default function that correctly handles multi-line input/output including the `Out[xx]=` cell labels?

Comment: Could it be `MakeExpression` ? The docs say "`MakeExpression` is used whenever boxes are supplied as input to Mathematica."

Comment: @Simon That's a fine guess but it's not the whole story.  If you try `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CellEvaluationFunction -> Function[Null, MakeExpression[##], HoldAll]]` you'll get `ErrorBox` for output.  (Not that `HoldAll` should not be necessary for Box form but I'm covering that as well.)  Once again there *appears* to be something funny going on here, where `Identity` and `MakeExpression` are handled specially.  I'm trying to figure out how to change the Box form then send it to the *true* default function for correct processing.

Comment: Ah, I see. There does appear to be special handling. Even `CellEvaluationFunction :> (Null; Identity)` doesn't work.

Comment: Based on [LinkSnooper](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html) it is based on `MakeExpression`.  The FE sends `EnterExpressionPacket@MakeExpression@BoxData[..]`.  I get errors like you do, if I do it myself, so it must be handled specially.

Comment: It seems to me that what you're after will have to be done via [MathLink packets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathLinkPackets.html). The In/Out names, for instance, are handled with [`InputNamePacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputNamePacket.html), [`OutputNamePacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OutputNamePacket.html).  If you're lucky, a solution won't be version dependent.

Comment: @Michael Good info; thanks.  I'm hoping there is an internal function I can call that automates this whole process so I don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: I was fast enough to fix it, though you might like [the V7 version](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html)

Answer (score 2):

The documentations says that "CellEvaluationFunction is applied to the BoxData expression representing the input to be evaluated". So I think Identity is working normally here. See the followings:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction -> function]

In[1]:= 2 + 2
        5 + 7

Out[1]= function[BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}], StandardForm]
```

So, if we take the BoxData structure of the above input, we can do some tests:

```
Identity[BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}]]
(* BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}] *)

# &[BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}]]
(* BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}] *)
```

So, Identity sends the expression BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}] to the kernel and it produces the two lines of output with different Out[number] like

```
In[1]:= 2 + 2
        5 + 7
```

On the other hand, ToExpression is declared as working on strings and boxes interpreting them as inputs, that means if set as CellEvaluationFunction it manipulates the box structure before to send it to the kernel:

```
ToExpression[BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}]]

12
```

So, I guess Identity is actually the CellEvaluationFunction's default.
The only think I cannot understand is why when we set an arbitrary function (like in my first example) as CellEvaluationFunction, the result includes the StandardForm as second argument (function[BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}], StandardForm]) while Identity doesn't accept a second argument and, indeed, it's not used.

**EDIT**

Using (#&) it fails but using (#)& it works:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction -> (# &)]

In[78]:= 2 + 2

Out[78]= BoxData[RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}]]

In[79]:= 2 + 2
5 + 7

Out[79]= BoxData[{RowBox[{"2", "+", "2"}], RowBox[{"5", "+", "7"}]}]


SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction -> (#) &]

In[74]:= 2 + 2

Out[74]= 4

In[75]:= 2 + 2
5 + 7

Out[75]= 4

Out[76]= 12
```

Comment: Bob, thanks for responding.  I fear I haven't phrased this question adequately.  I pointed out that using `(# &)` in place of `Identity` causes this to fail.  The thing is I want to use `CellEvaluationFunction` to modify the Box data (like `$PreRead`), then send it along to the kernel as usual.  So far everything I've tried has failed.  Sure, I can get a kind of output and display it with `CellPrint` but it doesn't have the `Out[xx]=` labels and is a hack.

Comment: Regarding your update, I'm sorry to inform you that you're being fooled by evaluation order.  If you use [these methods](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) you will see that the entirety of  `CellEvaluationFunction -> (#) &` is the `Function`, which by itself is inert, therefore you are not making an Option setting at all.

Comment: You are right, I was indeed surprised of the difference. I'm still looking at some alternatives, to no avail.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the labels is just a matter of using `CellLabel -> ($Line /. l_ :> ToString@Unevaluated@Out@l)`. If you care about getting the main loop split for every line, you can also code it but, that's just hacking down the hack. I wouldn't know how to programatically "really" split the main loop. Other than using other hacks like an invisible notebook and `NotebookEvaluate`, hummm

Comment: The main loop splitting seeeeems to me happens before the `CellEvaluationFunction` gets evaluated by the kernel, so I don't have high hopes for an unhacky clean solution. But who knows

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for your thoughts on this. I'm hoping there is some undocumented function [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29246/121) that we can use, rather than having to construct one as you describe (and risk introducing all kinds of subtle bugs).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can modify the [`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEvaluationFunction) to achieve your goal. On the other hand, you can modify [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression) instead, as [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression) is called on each line of input. So:

```
MakeExpression[x_,form_] /; !TrueQ@flag && TrueQ@override := Block[{flag=True},
    List/@MakeExpression[x,form]
]
```

The above code will add a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List) wrapper to every evaluated expression, but only when the `override` variable is [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True):

```
override = True;
2+2
5+7
```

> {4}
>
> {12}

Setting `override` back to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) will restore the normal behavior:

```
override = False;
2+2
5+7
```

> {Null}
>
> 4
>
> 12

Answer (score 1):

The front-end sends a `EnterExpressionPacket` to the kernel, which contains a expression like `MakeExpression[]`. As you had found, it has a different behavior to the real `MakeExpression` which exposed to users.

However, there is a kernel function for users which is able to handle multi-line input:

```
BoxForm`TopLevelMakeExpression
```

But it's still not exactly the real default one. For any `CellEvaluationFunction` except `MakeExpression`, the kernel

- always single `ReturnExpressionPacket` except multiple packets
- always use `ReturnExpressionPacket` instead of `ReturnInputFormPacket` etc.
- never send `OutputNamePacket["Out[1]= //MatrixForm"]` etc. for `$OutputForms`

Seems that `CellEvaluationFunction` is not a interface good enough for user-customization.