# Want actual cell data from CellEvaluationFunction

Tags: notebooks, version-9, printing, cells

Let's say I print a cell like so.

```
CellPrint@Cell[
  BoxData[" "], "Input", Evaluatable -> True, 
  CellEvaluationFunction -> Function[Print[#];]
  ]
```

Now I type in several lines of text in the `Cell` in *Mathematica*.

For example

```
1


2
```

I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and get the following output.

```
BoxData[List["1","3"]]
```

But when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, the `Cell`s content is really

```
BoxData[
  RowBox[{" ", 
     RowBox[{
       "1", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "3"}]}]]
```

Why doesn't `CellEvaluationFuction` receive the actual cell data? Is there a hidden function/argument that might give me such information?

Comment: According to the docs, "[`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEvaluationFunction.html) is applied to the `BoxData` expression **representing** the input to be evaluated." [Emphasis mine.]  The docs do not say that the Front End won't substitute some simplification of the expression in the cell.  I believe for `TagBox` and `InterpretationBox`, the difference might be quite a bit different.  At the least, one should not be surprised that any "typesetting" differences are stripped.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay then a workaround would be appreciated to achieve such functionality.  I am working on a workaround using `CellTags` right now, but I have some doubts on how dependable it will be with multiple cells.

Comment: Related: [(13317)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121) -- `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[string, False]` would give the unmodified Box form for that `string`.  This is not directly applicable but it may be useful at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your `CellEvaluationFunction` this:

```
Function[Print[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]]];]
```

Note that `EvaluationCell` (and the `CellObject` it creates) are new to version 9.

Comment: John, would you please take a look at my question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29264/121)?  Also, can this answer be made to work in v7 by using `SelectionMove` and `EvaluationCell`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't have version 7 to test but I willing to be this works in v7 also.  Basically I just read the entire notebook and extract the needed `Cell`.  You could probably use `CellId`s in replacement of `CellTag`s.  http://pastebin.com/FmCEPju6

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The use of `EvaluationCell` as a selector for `SelectionMove`, while no longer supported in v9, still seems to work, and also works in older versions.  E.g., `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]`

Comment: @JohnFultz Sorry for the confusion I was talking about my linked code.  http://pastebin.com/FmCEPju6  I was responding to Mr.Wizard's comment.  It doesn't use `EvaluationCell` but `NoteebokRead[InputNotebook[]]`

Comment: @Liam Actually, my comment was confused and didn't make much sense.  SE wouldn't let me edit it anymore, so I just deleted it.