# What's the differences between the shift-enter and MakeBoxes running?

Tags: symbolic

I know the example usages of MakeBoxes in the Tutorial like this.
but I want to know a subtle distinction between (1) and (3)

```
gplus /: MakeBoxes[gplus[x_, y_, n_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm], 
   SubscriptBox["\[CirclePlus]", MakeBoxes[n, StandardForm]], 
   MakeBoxes[y, StandardForm]}]
```

In(1)

```
MakeBoxes[gplus[a, b, m + n], StandardForm]
```

Out(1)

> RowBox[{"a", SubscriptBox["[CirclePlus]", RowBox[{"m", "+", "n"}]], 
>     "b"}]

In(2)

```
MakeBoxes[gplus[a, b, m + n], StandardForm] // RawBoxes
```

Out(2)

> [image]

In(3)

```
gplus[a, b, m + n]
```

Out(3)

> [image]

I had thought that if I type the In(1) then it will be like to Out(3).
I want to know the diffenrences after In(1) enter typing and In(3) enter typing.
When I type the shift-enter keys. what the front end mechanism does like RawBoxes to do.

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between output (1) and output (2).  What should I be looking at?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't well explain of that. Just I want to know intrinsic processes after type shift-enter.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your question, unless perhaps it is akin to my own here: [(29264)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29264).  Are you asking how expressions in a Notebook are evaluated?  Okay, I just saw your comment above.

Comment: I think I now know what you want but I don't have time to give a proper answer.  If someone hasn't already done that tomorrow I'll try to remember to do so.

Comment: My short answer would be: to get the expected notebook display, you have to feed the boxes to [DisplayForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DisplayForm.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a pretty specific answer. If this is less information than you are asking for feel free to comment or edit the question and I will expand.

As you know, the frontend represents expressions using boxes. These are wrappers that are concerned with appearance, and are peripheral to core symbolic evaluation. Therefore, each step of the [evaluation procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) generally entails stripping boxes, evaluating symbolically, and adding boxes back as appropriate. But this is happening at every layer of an expression, and how boxes are dealt with may itself involve some evaluation.

Loosely speaking, then, when you hit `SHIFT`+`ENTER`, three things happen at every layer. Mathematica uses `MakeExpression` to rearrange boxes into canonical forms, then it evaluates those expressions, then it wraps them using `MakeBoxes`. We can override different parts of this process as we please.

Let's start at the beginning.

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"f", "[", x_, "]"}], form_] := (
  Print@"MakeExpression";
  MakeExpression[RowBox[{"g", "[", x, "+", "2", "]"}], form]);
f[1 + 2]
```

> MakeExpression
>
> g[5]

We can see that this transformation occurs prior to evaluation.

```
f[1 + 2] // Hold
```

> MakeExpression
>
> Hold[g[(1 + 2) + 2]]

Similarly,

```
g[x_] := (
  Print@"g";
  h[x]);
f[1 + 2]
```

> MakeExpression
>
> g
>
> h[5]

Once evaluation is complete, the expression is rewrapped.

```
MakeBoxes[h[x_], form_] := (
  Print@"MakeBoxes";
  MakeBoxes[i[x], form]);
f[1 + 2]
```

> MakeExpression
>
> g
>
> MakeBoxes
>
> i[5]

What comes out of `MakeBoxes` does not get interpreted as input.

```
Attributes@MakeBoxes
```

> {HoldAllComplete}

```
MakeBoxes[h[1 + 2]]
```

> MakeBoxes
>
> RowBox[{"i", "[", RowBox[{"1", "+", "2"}], "]"}]

`RawBoxes` is just a wrapper that tells Mathematica not to transform what's inside into boxes. In other words, it indicates what's inside has already been wrapped, and Mathematica renders it directly.

```
% //RawBoxes
```

> i[1 + 2]

We can confirm that this is not being interpreted as input.

```
i[x_] := "foo";
MakeBoxes[h[1 + 2]] // RawBoxes
```

> MakeBoxes
>
> i[1 + 2]

But copy that and paste it in a new cell:

```
i[1 + 2]
```

> "foo"

And we are back full circle to `MakeExpression`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want to know and this is helpful for making operator of ODE.