# Reading Cells or Boxes expression by expression

Tags: notebooks, expression-manipulation, conversion, boxes

Let's say we have a cell:

---

```
(*newline*)
(*newline*)
Plot[
    x, 
    {x, 0, 1}
]
(*newline*)    
Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}]
```

---

#### How to read it expression by expression?

So e.g to read `Plots` one by one, in whatever form, `Boxes`, `Hold[expression]`, `String`?

Here's my attempt:

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[] (*cellobject in general*), All, Cell];

text = First[  FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookSelection[], "InputText"]]
]; (*1*)

Module[{stream = StringToStream[text], temp},
   temp = ReadList[stream, Hold[Expression]];
   Close[stream];
   temp
]
```

> ```
> {Hold[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]], Hold[Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}]]}
> ```

Quite long, and problematic because it changes selection.

I think there should be better way since this is what FrontEnd is doing anyway, reading expression by expression:

```
{
    1, Abort[]
}
2
```

> ```
> $Aborted
> 2
> ```

---

`(*1*)` - [How do I extract the contents of a selected cell as plain text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/5478)

Comment: At least tangentially related: [(29264)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29264/121)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `SelectionMove` and `NotebookSelection` one can use `NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]` and then cleanup the text returned by the `ExportPacket`.

```
Thread @ MakeExpression[
 "{" <> 
  StringReplace[
   First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]], "InputText"]]], 
   {"\r\n " -> "", "\r\n" -> ","}] 
  <> "}", 
 StandardForm] /. HoldComplete[Null] :> Nothing
```

Output for the two examples:

> ```
> {HoldComplete[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]], HoldComplete[Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}]]}
> ```

and

> ```
> {HoldComplete[{1, Abort[]}], HoldComplete[2]}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight modification of Karsten's answer. Previously I felt it was too similar, but I suppose it cannot hurt to post it. The main difference is that I avoid `MakeExpression`. I also like the alternative in your question, which is to use `StringToStream`.

```
read[cObj_] :=
 DeleteCases[#, HoldComplete[Null]] &@(
   ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
      HoldComplete] & /@
    (StringSplit[#, "\n"] &)@
     First@FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookRead@cObj, "PlainText"]
   )
```

Comment: Not general enough, if you have a cell indentical as my example: `{"(*newline*)\r", "(*newline*)\r", "Plot[\r", "x,\r", "{x,0,1}\r", "]\
\r", "(*newline*)\r", "Plot[x,{x,0,2}]"} ` so `StringSplit` has to be more careful.

Comment: @Kuba hmm thats strange, I thought `"\n"` caught all newlines on my other computer (OSX).