# NotebookImport fails for code split over multiple lines

Tags: bugs, import, notebooks

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

I've found that `NotebookImport[file,"Input" -> "HeldInterpretedCell"]` doesn't seem to cope when the closing bracket of a command is on the following line of an input cell.

So if I save a notebook test.nb with the following input cell (as one cell):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}
 ]
```

Then `NotebookImport["test.nb","Input" -> "HeldInterpretedCell"]` gives a `Failure[]` box instead of the expected `HoldComplete[Plot[x,{x,0,1}]]`.

With multiple different cells with different permutations:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}
 ]

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[x,
 {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[
 x,
 {x, 0, 1}]
```

the first and last will fail, but the middle two are fine. It looks like it is related to the square brackets of the outmost command being the end/start of a line.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I'd say so, meanwhile you can probably use ideas from: [Reading Cells or Boxes expression by expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114208/5478)

Comment: I asked the question based on the answers in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146167 sometimes giving errors, and traced it back to this. I can probably hack the part out of the Failure[] box that I need.

Comment: Not only `"HeldInterpretedCell"` but also `"InterpretedCell"` fails miserably. I think it is a bug, definitely worth reporting.

Comment: With versions 11.0.1 and 10.4.1 I get the same failure for `"HeldInterpretedCell"` and `"InterpretedCell"` as with version 11.1.1.

Comment: Bug submitted to Wolfram.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug by Wolfram Support.

Comment: Wolfram emailed me to let me know this has been fixed in v11.2, which I've confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Support emailed me to let me know that this has been fixed in v11.2, which I've confirmed.