# Is there some way to have only one input, but can give two Output Cells?

Tags: front-end

It is well known that there are as many output cells as there are rows of input

[image]

Is there some way to have only one input, but can give two Output Cells.

For example:

```
eval["
    1+1
    1+1
"]
```

gets two output.

Note that excluding the use of *CellPrint Output Label*, I actually want to know how to trick the front end into multiple input.

related: [What is the real default CellEvaluationFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29264/what-is-the-real-default-cellevaluationfunction)

Comment: You can have as many `CellPrint` as you want in your code. Each one will produce a cell which you can make it look like an output cell or whatever you want. But this is technically a side effect, not an output.