# What is the symbol FE`None for?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, random, conditional

I have run into the symbol

> FE`None

multiple times. What is this symbol, and what is it designed to indicate? All I could find is that FE indicates the front-end, but it's unfortunately a very Ungoogleable term. I believe that it's not something I should ever "see" on the front, but I'm guessing it represents some sort of display element. Perhaps "this object is un-representable to the front end" or something like?

To be clear, I'm not asking for aid in fixing my program so as to not produce this output. This is a question about the definition of the symbol, out of purely intellectual curiosity.

**Edit**: After a long while debugging the application, I've managed to reduce the problematic code that caused this happen. See, it was doing some fuzzy logic computations, and various computations were being represented using `If` statements. For instance `If[True,a,b]` evaluates to `a` always, then `If[var,a,b]` could be used to represent a fuzzy mixture of `a` and `b`. (This was not my design decision.) Then the computations were implemented as different overloads of `If`. Naturally, this meant `Unprotect`ing `If` as well.

Through a chain of some slightly-off `Hold`s and `Evaluate`s, confusing `=` and `:=`, there was some code that ended up running under certain circumstances to evaluate to:

```
Unprotect[If];
Unprotect[If];
If[True,a_,b_] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.5,a,b];
```

I think it's pretty obvious how this could could lead to some weird problems down the line. As a minimal case, run the above, followed by `If[True,1,2]`. I tested on a few different versions of Mathematica on different machines, it seems to consistently produce `2`, with a "Full output could not be displayed" warning. Pressing "Show full output" 3 times then waiting 15 minutes caused the output to re-render as "FE`None".

Comment: I doubt this is answerable unless someone happens to have experienced the exact same problem.  Can you provide any more information about your application?

Comment: Ah, it's more me just kind of playing around / messing with the environment a bit, to learn what it does. I don't expect help with what steps to take it counteract it in my case, I'd just like to know what it means. In the same sense that if I asked "what is NaN?" I wouldn't expect someone to tell me whether it was division by 0 or Infinity-Infinity... but I could expect them to tell me what a NaN is.

Comment: ``FE` `` Symbols are used by the Front End as part of its normal operations. (e.g. [(29244)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29244/121))  Why one is "leaking" out to a returned evaluation I cannot say.

Comment: Closed? :/ But I'm not asking for help in fixing code. I'm just asking for the definition of a symbol (that happens to be produced by an error in my case). I amended the question to make this clear.

Comment: Can you add some code that returns ``FE`None``?

Comment: The Symbol *has no definition*; it is simply [`None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/None.html) in the Front End context.  The curiosity about in my mind seems firmly centered on *why* this was returned by an evaluation and we still do not have even a description of the code you were running.  This is why I joined three other longstanding members in voting to close.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My random guess, FWIW, is that ``FE`None`` works like ``System`None`` in certain ``FE` `` functions, and it's in the ``FE` `` context for security reasons.  I agree it would be nice to have code to reproduce its top-level appearance.

Comment: I'll work on creating a minimal example, then. Thanks for your info so far!

Comment: I added reproducing code. You won't like it though :(

Comment: Did you know that `If[]` has a *fourth* argument?

Comment: Yes, although that would not have ended up relevant for the work we were doing. With the patterns we *meant* to run, that shouldn't be important either (since we only consider 3-argument uses).